# Отключение содержимого панелей по getName()

Tags: java, swing

На форме есть некоторое кол-во панелей, на которых элементы управления. Нужно снимать `Enabled` c тех или иных панелей (и их элементов управления).

Есть 3 метода:
первый получает в коллекцию названия панелей.

второй отключает элементы управления:

```
    private void setComponentsProperty(
        javax.swing.JPanel panel, int action) {
    //action = 0-выключить, 1-включить
        Component[] selectedFilds = panel.getComponents();
        for (int i = 0; i < panel.getComponentCount(); i++) {
            Component currentComponent = selectedFilds[i];
            if (action == 0) {
                currentComponent.setEnabled(false);
            } else {
                currentComponent.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
}
```

третий сравнивает имя панели с содержимым коллекции и передает панель во второй метод:

```
private void setAllDisable(Container parent) {
      for (Component comp : parent.getComponents()) {
            if (comp instanceof Container) {
                setAllDisable((Container) comp);
            }
            if (comp instanceof JPanel) {
                for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(i);
                    if (comp.getName().equals(v.get(i))) {//на этой проверке ошибка

                        setComponentsProperty((JPanel) comp, 0);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

на этапе сравнения `getName` с элементом коллекции получаю `nullpointer`.
Подскажите, где я вляпался?

Comment: А что такое `v`?

Comment: а Вы присваиваете имя данному компоненту? ибо NullPointer будет выскакивать только по той причине что у Component поле name=null;

Comment: Dex 
v- ArrayList

Viacheslav 
да, имя компоненту присваиваю, такое же как имя переменной. Не может быть в этом проблемы?

Comment: или воспользуйтесь отладчиком или сделайте вывод на экран как comp.getName() так и v.get(i)

Comment: причина найдена: использовался сторонний датачузер, внутри которого была панель, помог гетпарент